# Масштабируемая система сортировки по параметрам

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как написать систему для сортировки данных по параметрам, чтобы она хорошо масштабировалась вне зависимости от количества всевозможных параметров? Например, есть условный json-формат, в котором хранятся данные:

```
{
    "city": "Москва",
    "population": "12",
    "standart_of_living": "9.5",
    "per_capita_income": "50000",
    "trust_in_government": "9.8"
}
```

Если писать код на JavaScript, то получается статический цикл без возможности динамически добавлять/удалять параметры. И если бы я писал простенькую статическую выборку, то сделал бы так:

```
for(let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    if(json[i].population >= 10 && json[i].standart_of_living >= 8)
        $('#some_div').append("Город: " + json[i].city);
}
```

Результатом работы цикла был бы вывод `Город: Москва`. Но что, если пользователь на странице захочет выбирать города ещё и по параметру "Уровень доверия к правительству"(trust_in_government)? Код-то у меня статичен и я не могу в него динамически добавить параметр `&& json[i].trust_in_government >= 9`. Существует ли алгоритм, позволяющий реализовать сортировку по параметрам без необходимости строчить горы кода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует метод [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), который позволяет сократить написанный вами код до одной строки:

```
json.filter(i => i.population>9 && i.standart_of_living>7).forEach(i => $('#some_div').append(`Город: ${i.city}`));
```

С помощью композиции и метода [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) легко использовать его для фильтрации по любым параметрам:

```
let rules = [
    {prop: 'population', val: 9},
    {prop: 'standart_of_living', val: 7},
];
json.filter(i => rules.every(rule => i[rule.prop]>rule.val))
```

Единственная проблема, что нельзя в массив правил запихнуть оператор сравнения. 
Но можно положить его туда в виде строки, и использовать с помощью [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), [конструктора Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) или банального switch, примерно так:

```
let rules = [
    {prop: 'population', val: 9, op: '=='},
    {prop: 'standart_of_living', val: 7, op: '>'},
];
// Вариант с eval самый короткий, если бы я делал не для примера, я бы использовал switch:
json.filter(i => rules.every(rule => eval(`${i[rule.prop]}${rule.op}${rule.val}`)))
```

Теперь вместо того, чтоб строчить горы кода, для каждого нового правила фильтрации вам надо добавить три параметра в массив правил - что сравнивать, как сравнивать, с чем сравнивать.

```js
const json = [
    {a:1, b:2, c: 'Test'},
    {a:1, b:20, c: 'Hello world'},
    {a:1, b:-2, c: 'Test'},
    {a:1, b:'2', c: 'Hello world'},
    {a:'Hello world', c: 'Test'},
    {a:1, b:[], c: 'Test'}
];
// Вариант с switch:
const filter = rules => json.filter(i => rules.every(rule => {
    switch (rule.op){
        case "===": return i[rule.prop] === rule.val;
        case "==": return i[rule.prop] == rule.val;
        case "!=": return i[rule.prop] != rule.val;
        case "!==": return i[rule.prop] !== rule.val;
        case ">": return i[rule.prop] > rule.val;
        case "<": return i[rule.prop] < rule.val;
        case "<=": return i[rule.prop] <= rule.val;
        case ">=": return i[rule.prop] >= rule.val;
        default: return false;
    }
}));

console.log(filter([{prop: 'a', val: 1, op: '!='}]));
console.log(filter([{prop: 'b', val: 0, op: '>'}]));
console.log(filter([{prop: 'b', val: undefined, op: '==='}]));
```

Comment: Супер, спасибо! То есть, чтобы добавить новое правило, я могу, например, сделать привязку к checkbox. И когда checkbox будет отмечен, вызывать метод `push()` и вставлять новое правило в массив правил?

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin как вариант. Можете для тренировки модифицировать данный алгоритм так, чтоб он проверял вложенные поля)

Comment: Снова здравствуйте. Со временем логика в моём приложении изменилась и массивы стали объектами. Теперь у меня и `rules` - объект, и `json` - объект. Не могли бы вы описать логику приложения, чтобы я смог самостоятельно переписать алгоритм? Сейчас я понимаю, что это работает так - есть два цикла, один вложен в другой(every вложен в filter). В `switch` проверяется, совпадает ли операция с тем, что указано в `rule.op` и возвращает булево значение. Если true, то элемент массива json пушится во временный массив. Если false - нет.

Comment: Попробовал [переписать](https://repl.it/NkdX) это под себя - ничего не получилось. Получаю пустой объект.